# AddProximityAlert power consumption on Android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, power-management

I am developing a GeoFencing Android App that notifies user whenever they are close to a certain region (similar to Start Monitoring for Region in iOS).

I know I can use AddProximityAlert in Android but I am concern about the power consumption as I will add around 50 geo points.

The question is: would the power consumption change on adding more points ? or it will stay the same regardless how many points I added ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to make tests to know for sure :-) But my understanding is that the LocationManager checks periodically the current position (one "expensive" GPS check every 4 minutes if screen is off, more often if it's on, couldn't find how often) and then compares the location with all the registered center-points. So the power consumption, GPS-wise, is limited, and after that it's just "normal" CPU consumption created by checking an array of points.

HTH

Comment: yea I understand that as well but is there any reliable source for such an information ? if not, then what would be a good testing method to calculate that in accurate way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any tests before but I think the power consumption depends on hardware refreshing rate. You can set up a comparison test with no geo-point and multiple geo-point. You may need to stand still to ensure the same GPS visibility. And use some power consumption tool, such as Battery Historian, to evaluate the power consumption.